# html use multiple tag in a tag

Tags: seo, google, html

My code is :

```
<article class="product">
    <a href="#">
        <h2>My product title</h2>
        <p>My product small description and text</p>
        <span>Read more »</span>
    </a>
</article>
```

Is my code correct and good for seo ?

Answer (score 0):

your linking whole text , header and paragraph and span
it's better just link "read more "